# How to create a string like this in latex?

Tags: fonts, macros, symbols, color

I am writing a report, where I have to use a string like this below at several instances of my report. I am not sure how to do this.

[image: Desired text]

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: As a not-really-constructive comment: it is plain silly to use a company logo in running text.

Comment: @Matsmath It is to mention in appendix that I am using this. For example, this is used at the title of my appendix.

Comment: it is a logo not text so just use `\includegraphics{somefile}` to include it where needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I know, but I want to create a string like this and I dont want this as a logo. I require this logo as a string instead, so that in my report I can use this inline with other texts.

Comment: you can use it inline anyay `blah blah a sentence about \includegraphics[height=1.2ex]{logo.png} and some more text`

Comment: You can not, in most font technologies available to tex, have a font with only partially coloured glyphs as in the i here so you can not do this as simple text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any brute force method to achieve this?? Other than including this as a figure, and here I am using "Palatino" font style in my report and thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: I don't see the point. If you want the logo you should use exactly the logo (often there are trademark infringements if you fake it) so you should use `\includegraphics`. If you just want text use `PRODRIVE` as text, perhaps in sans serif font if you wish

Comment: @Matsmath sillier than `\LaTeX` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the dot accent raised and shifted by one italic correction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgheros,xcolor}
\newcommand\prodrive{\textsf{\textit{PRODR\textcolor{red}{\raise .5ex \rlap{\kern\fontdimen1\font\char95}}IVE}}}
\begin{document}
foo \prodrive\ bar

\large foo \prodrive\ bar

\Large foo \prodrive\ bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: In the OP the red dot on the letter I is round. Also, would it be possible to match the *exact same* color red as in the OP (by means of, e.g., specifying RGB values)?

Comment: @Matsmath Yes, that's possible.  Just color-pick the correct color code from the picture and define it via `\definecolor{correctred}{<model>}{<values>}`.  To have a round dot, I'd use `$\cdot$` instead of `\.{}` (the shifts have to be adjusted, of course) or see Fran's answer; there the `\dot` math accent is used.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that easily with `pstricks`. The numerical values of some parameters have to be adapted, depending on the font used. I used `Gillius2`, a free font close to Gill Sans. The parameters  seem to be OK with any font size, since they're expressed in `ex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border =3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{Gillius2}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Huge
  PRODR\psDefBoxNodes{I}{I}VE%
  \uput{0.4ex}[80](I:tr){\dotnode[linecolor=red, dotsize=0.28ex]{X}}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Beranrd can this be used inline with other texts.

Answer (score 5):

For the default font with `pdflatex` this simple macro seems enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,amsmath}
\def\PROVIDE{{\textsl{\sffamily{PRODR{\color{red}%
$\dot{\text{\color{black}I }}\kern-.3em$}VE}}}}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
\huge       The \PROVIDE\ logo
\Large      The \PROVIDE\ logo
\normalsize The \PROVIDE\ logo
\scriptsize The \PROVIDE\ logo
\tiny       The \PROVIDE\ logo
\end{document}
```

[image]